# eliminate duplicate row in dataframe and keep the row with specific string value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```
import pandas as pd 

dfa = {'account':['a','b','a','c','a'],
      'ret_type':['CTR','WO','T','CTR','T'],
      'val':['0.0','0.1','0.2','0.3','0.4'],
      'ins_date':['11','12','11','13','14']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dfa)

    account ret_type     val    ins_date
0     a       CTR        0.0    11
1     b       WO         0.1    12
2     a       T          0.2    11
3     c       CTR        0.3    13
4     a       T          0.4    14
```

I have a requirement that I need to eliminate the duplicate row such that

```
1 duplicate row means combination of (account,ins_dat) 
2 if duplicate found i need to keep row with ret type CTR abd drop row with T
3 i dont want to delete T rows for which no duplicate row is there like 4
4 in this example fr ex 2nd row is deleted as output finally
```

how should i do this?

Comment: What is desired output? Just post that  so will be easy to read.

Comment: as mentioned in 4th line desired output is df without row 2 a T 0.2 11

Comment: based on combination of  `account, return_type,ins_dat ` there is no duplicates in your example. can you please add some.

Comment: sorry based on account and ins_date only

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['account', 'ins_date'])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this. You will get answer.

```
df["duplicated"] = df[["account", "ins_date"]].duplicated(keep=False)
df = df[(df.ret_type == 'CTR') | ~df["duplicated"]]
```

Comment: Great one. faster too. +1

Comment: yeah df = pd.DataFrame(dfa)
df["duplicate"] = df[["account", "ins_date"]].duplicated(keep=False)
print(df)

df1 = df.loc[(df['ret_type']=='T') & (df['duplicate'] == True) ]

df = df[~df.isin(df1)].dropna()

df

Comment: "AlarmName" : {"Fn::Join" : ["", [
               {"Ref" : "AppId"}, ",",
               {"Ref" : "AppServerAG"}, ":", "HealthCheck", ",", "MAJOR"]]},

Answer (score 0):

you can loop and check for duplicates using

> a map of account and ret_type combination

---  and then drop that row using the index.

```
map ={}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(map[row['account']]):
        if(map[row['account']] == row['ret_type']):
            df.drop(df.index[index])
    else:
        map[row['account']] = row['ret_type']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood you:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['account', 'ins_date'])
  account ret_type  val ins_date
0       a      CTR  0.0       11
1       b       WO  0.1       12
3       c      CTR  0.3       13
4       a        T  0.4       14
```

Comment: THIS WONT WORK  as i need to keep the row with ret_typ CTR and not T . if I get a ret type T row first then it will retain that

Comment: So, what difference it makes apart from True /False Boolean columns?